# insertedID when i was using then it not show in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    var sql="Insert into Employee(name) values('Pravin')";
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
        if(err)throw err;
        /*Use the result object to get id*/
        console.log("1 record inserted , ID"+result.insertedID);
    });

});
```

1 record inserted , IDundefined
not able get Id number in this

Comment: 1 record inserted , IDundefined  it is showing

Comment: how about insertId? Dump (console.log) result object